# How to access property in object according to array

Tags: javascript

so i have an array like this:

```
var arr=[one, lol];
```

and an object like this

```
var obj={
    one:{
        lol:11234
    }
}
```

How do I make it so if i do obj[lol] then it will print out 11234? Keep in mind I don't know how long the array is and answers like console.log(obj[one][lol]) doesn't work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to try like this :

    obj["one"]["lol"]

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/5395773

Comment: This sounds like the xy problem. Why do you need this? What is the problem behind this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the previous property's value (initially `obj`) and continue to loop until end of array like so:

```js
var arr = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

var obj = {
  one: {
    two: {
      three: 11234
    }
  }
}

var currentProp = obj;

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  currentProp = currentProp[arr[i]];
}

console.log(currentProp);
```

The above code will start at the object `obj`, then loop until the array's length, and reassign `currentProp` to the next property in the array as it goes. In this case, this is what it does:

- First iteration, access `obj[arr[0]]`, which is `one`, and assign it to `currentProp`
- Second iteration, access `obj[arr[0]][arr[1]]` or `one[arr[1]]`, which is `two`, and assign it to `currentProp`
- Third iteration, access `obj[arr[0]][arr[1]][arr[2]]` or `two[arr[2]]`, which is `three`, and assign it to `currentProp`. Loop then terminates as it has reached end of the list.

In the end, the value of the last property will be in `currentProp`, and will correctly output 11234.

Comment: is there any way to make it so if i do obj[three] and it will return 11234?

Comment: @eclipseIzHere No. Bracket notation looks for a prop of the object, it doesn't look for descendants or nested objects. You would have to manually traverse the object and search it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try like this :

```
obj["one"]["lol"]
```

JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/3we2ohy6/1/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are just looking up a property value it is simpler to do:

```
console.log(obj.one.lol);
```

Doing it using the square brackets the way you have it JS thinks both the one and LOL are variables. Unless you wrap them in quotes.

```
console.log(obj['one']['lol');
```

You will not get to the value you are looking for the way you are doing it unless you create a function that either restructures the obj object or you feed it the obj.one as a property.

Comment: @Upvoter how does this answer the question? This is hardcoded, not dynamic!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), because this returns the object you need, without keeping a reference outside.

```js
function set(object, path, value) {
    var last = path.pop();

    path.reduce(function (o, k) {
        return o[k] = o[k] || {};
    }, object)[last] = value;
}

var obj = {};

set(obj, ['one', 'lol'], '11234'); 
   
console.log(obj);
```